# is there a service that creates EOS or TRX div tokens?

Tags: smart-contract

is there a service that creates EOS or TRX div tokens? Or can someone point me in the right direction?

Thank you

Comment: Could you please specify your question more precisely? I have no idea what you mean exactly.

Comment: hi sure, sorry it wasn't clear enough. 

there are services like https://smartz.io/ or https://www.togen.io/ on ETH that create dividend tokens for you. I'd like to know if there are services that can do the same for EOS or TRX. dividend tokens would be smart tokens that you can issue divs to holders of said tokens